# Matrix closed under subtraction

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, ring-theory

I am trying to show that the set

$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\,\middle|\; a,b\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$

is a subring of $M_2(\mathbb Z)$ (the $2\times2$ matrix ring over the integers). However I am struggling to show that it is closed under subtraction. When I do the subtraction, I just get the matrix of all $0$'s even though I know it is not correct. Can I set it up so I am subtracting the $a,b$ matrix from another matrix with the top line $c,d$ because $a$ and $b$ can be any integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you said at the end is correct. You want to show that given two arbitrary matrices in this set, their difference will still be in the set. So call the set $S$ and let $A,B\in S$. Then we can write

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}c&d\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

for $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then

$$A-B=\begin{pmatrix}a-c&b-d\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

which is an element of $S$ because $a-c$ and $b-d$ are both integers, so we have closure under subtraction.